# Parse push notifications send data

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-server

I am trying to send data in my payload in a Parse push notification.

```
Parse.Push.send({
   where: pushQuery,      // for sending to a specific channel
   data: payload,
   }, { success: function() {
   console.log("#### PUSH OK");
   }, error: function(error) {
   console.log("#### PUSH ERROR" + error.message);
   }, useMasterKey: true});

   response.success('success');
});
```

In my payload, I store a customData field. How can i access this field in my onReceive() in my custom broadcast receiver;

Answer (score 0):

You should probably work with this in you Android App if your result is a Bundle

```
/**
 * Called when message is received.
 * @param from SenderID of the sender.
 * @param data Data bundle containing message data as key/value pairs.
 * For Set of keys use data.keySet().
 */
override fun onMessageReceived(from: String?, data: Bundle?) {
    if (data != null) {
        val message = data.getString("text")
        val title = data.getString("title")
    }
 }
```

Comment: The overwritten function is onReceive(Context context, Intent intent). How do i access the bundle?

Comment: You can get the bundle of an intent, try to get the Bundle that will be the data